# Difference between a circuit and a normal function

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, terminology

I've seen the word circuit used in many crypto contexts (for example, regarding FHE [in this pdf](https://crypto.stanford.edu/craig/craig-thesis.pdf)). I've always thought of a circuit as another word for a program or function. But is there a difference - i.e., is there something that a standard function can do that a circuit can't?

Comment: By "normal function" do you mean the normal *mathematical* definition of a function or something else?

Comment: Not a mathematical function in the strict sense. I mean a computer program with inputs and outputs

Comment: I have a sub-question as well: If circuits and computer programs are equivalent, then how can we convert a given program into a circuit? Does there exist an algorithm to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A circuit is a representation of a (computable) function. There are many other ways to represent a function (mathematical notation, Turing machines, pseudo-code, etc.), but for some purposes it happens that circuits are the most convenient one.

Comment: Another (informal) distinction is that circuits as a representation (as opposed to physical circuits) generally _have no loops_, and are thus analyzable in simpler ways, e.g. circuit _depth_.

Comment: I have a sub-question as well: If circuits and computer programs are equivalent, then how can we convert a given program into a circuit? Does there exist an algorithm to do so?

Comment: @Itachi How do you define "computer program"? For example a C program is compiled to machine instructions, which are fairly easy to "translate" to a circuit.

Comment: @Itachi By the way, the source code distribution for the Pinocchio verifiable computing protocol includes a compiler to compile a program written in a subset of C to an arithmetic circuit. http://vc.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'll ask my doubt as an example: How to convert a C program with a while loop (which loops x number of times, where x an input to the program) into a circuit (whose structure is independent of the input)?

Comment: @Itachi This would be too long for a comment, you can read for example Chapter 6 of the book by Arora and Barak.